# Realm data isValid() false but can get data

Tags: android, realm

I use Realm to store data in my project. I have strange problem.
My model:

```
Class Post extends RealmObject implements Serializable{
  @PrimaryKey
  int id;
  ...
  RealmList<Post> subdata;

  RealmList<Post> getSubdata() {
      return subdata;
  }

}
```

I usually check  `getSubdata() != null && getSubdata().isValid()` to use the subdata. The problem is when I check   `getSubdata().isValid()` return `false`, but I still get data in `subdata`. It 's ok when I don't check `isValid`. Document says like this:

```
/**
     * Checks if the {@link RealmList} is managed by Realm and contains valid data i.e., the {@link io.realm.Realm}
     * instance hasn't been closed.
     *
     * @return {@code true} if still valid to use, {@code false} otherwise or if it's an unmanaged list.
     */
    public boolean isValid() {
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (realm == null || realm.isClosed()) {
            return false;
        }
        return isAttached();
    }
```

Updating debug:

[image]

Comment: I don't know why you can get data when Realm is invalid. But in my app whenever realm close and I try to get data from `RealmObject` my app will throw exception about Realm is invalid

Comment: That 's the reason I ask this question @PhanVanLinh

Comment: Is it managed or unmanaged data? Im guessing unmanaged

Comment: Oh, Sorry It 's my fault. I realized I changed it to unmanaged.

Answer (score 0):

Your class needs to extend RealmObject. so it should change to :

```
Class Post extends RealmObject {
  @PrimaryKey
  int id;
  ...
  RealmList<Post> subdata;

  RealmList<Post> getSubdata() {
      return subdata;
  }

}
```

Comment: It 's just example. I extended RealmObject.